# Finitely generated $k$-algebra which is a semi-local ring is finite $k$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and is a semi-local ring. How to show that $A$ is also a finite $k$-algebra?

Certainly we could assume that $A$ is a finite $k$-algebra $\iff$ $A$ is Artinian (Theorem). However it may be useless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equivalence is of big use: Since $A$ is noetherian by Hilbert's Basis theorem, we have that $A$ artinian is the same as $\dim A=0$, i.e. we have to show that any prime ideal is maximal.

Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal. A finitely generated $k$-algebra is a Jacobson ring, hence $\mathfrak p$ is the intersection of some maximal ideals. In particular $\mathfrak p$ contains the intersection of all maximal ideals. In particular $\mathfrak p$ contains the product of all (finitely many) maximal ideals. By the prime property $\mathfrak p$ contains one of the maximal ideals, hence is maximal itself.

Here is another very nice proof using Noether normalization:

Let $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_d] \hookrightarrow A$ be a Noether normalization of $A$. This map is finite, hence it gives rise to a surjection from the maximal ideals of $A$ to the maximal ideals of $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_d]$. From the assumption, we deduce that there are only finitely many maximal ideals in $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_d]$ which enforces the desired $d=0$: If $d \neq 0$, we have infintely many maximal ideals by looking at $(x_1, \dotsc, x_{d-1}, f(x_d))$ with $f$ running through the infinitely many irreducible polynomials of $k[x_d]$.

Comment: Thanks! This are really helpful to me. Whereas I haven’t understand "This map is finite" and what "finite" means. Could you say something more detailed?

Comment: A ring map $R \to S$ is called finite, if $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Actually the formulation of your problem uses that definition, since you want to proof that $k \to A$ is a finite map, i.e. $A$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space.

Comment: Oh I see it. Thank you for your kind patient explanation.

Comment: I have another question now. Why does "finite" imply that there is a surjection from the maximal ideals to maximal ideals?

Comment: This the Going Up Theorem.